# Vite Laravel SCSS - Dropping SCSS @import on hot reaload

Tags: css, laravel, sass, tailwind-css, vite

I've made a clean install for a Laravel project with Vite. As per the documentation. I've added Tailwind and SCSS to the project.

- When I run `npm run dev` the browser gets reloaded and renders the code as expected.
- Then I edit a Blade file. The browser reloads, updates the blade file, but drops the SCSS `@import`. In other words, the css markup is gone.
- When I edit a SCSS file. The browser reloads and updates all. So also runs the @import.

Simple example: app.scss

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Body background will be red, but all tailwind imports are gone. Also when using:

```
@import "~tailwindcss/base";
@import "~tailwindcss/components";
@import "~tailwindcss/utilities";
```

-- EDIT --
This seems to work. But is this a workaround, or is this the way?
vite.config.js

```
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `
                @import "./resources/scss/config/variables.scss";
                @import "./resources/scss/base/init.scss";
                `
            },
        },
    },
```